# Чем лучше реализовывать частые постоянные вычисления?

Tags: javascript

Необходимо выполнять определенный код 30-40 раз в секунду. Возможные задержки реализации надо учитывать, как и вариант, что код будет слишком тяжелым, чтобы исполнить за указанный участок времени.

Для отрисовки ввели `window.requestAnimationFrame`, а что ввели для вычислений?

Пользоваться `setTimeout` с `Date.getNow()` для определения времени, затраченного на выполнение кода - идея не очень. Раньше задержка `setTimeout` была 3-4мс, сейчас уменьшили до 0-2. Но все-равно, все задается в миллисекундах и погрешность довольно высока.

Ввели `Promises` - для другого, но я видел где-то безумную реализацию таймера на них.

Ввели `Web Workers` - по идее, то что надо - вычисления в отдельном потоке, без замедления основной страницы. У них там, вроде-бы, сложности с взаимодействием со страницей, но, по сути, это не особо то и нужно в большинстве случаев.

Добавили `window.performance.now()`, да и вообще время с микросекундами, что прекрасно, но реализацию высокоточного таймера на микросекундах я так и не увидел.

В общем, что использовать, для, грубо говоря, игры?

Comment: _а что ввели для вычислений?_ - а ничего

Comment: эм, как вы представляете себе принудительный обрыв выполнения кода?

Comment: Никак, просто последующие участки будут тормозить, если тяжело, ничего против не имею. По сути, мне нужен аналог requestAnimationFrame, но с возможностью задать свое кол-во "кадров" в секунду и с высокой точностью.

Comment: А ещё можно подумать над тем, нужно ли так сильно грузить браузер, выполняя тонны вычислений на JS. Возможно, вычисления можно оптимизировать. Или можно сделать отдельный клиент игры, вообще не ввязываясь в проблемы с JS и браузером.

Comment: @Regent это нынче не модно и не круто, сейчас в браузере принято делать **ВСЁ** ) Даже UT99 портировали на js -_-

Comment: Пожалуйста, выражайтесь по теме. Не вижу ничего плохого в браузерных приложениях.

Comment: @user64675 делал как то RTS, c WebWorkers я столкнулся с двумя сложностями - 1) асинхронность (например, находишь для юнита путь, но пока шли вычисления - игрок что то построил прямо в следующей клетке, и юнит вмуровывается в здание) 2) нельзя напрямую обработать объект, нужно тратить дополнительные усилия, чтобы сначала собрать нужные параметры в кучку, кинуть в воркер, вычислить там всё что надо, кинуть обратно, и собственно сложность - разобратся, к какому объекту какой параметр относился. По сути проблемы детские, решаются довольно легко

Comment: Не только игры. Ещё можно биткойны вычислять, пока пользователь смотрит на твою страницу!

Answer (score 1):

Вам могут помочь underscore функции
[Throttle](http://underscorejs.ru/#throttle) и 
[Debounce](http://underscorejs.ru/#throttle)

Я пользуюсь ими в проектах с requestAnimationFrame для снижения нагрузок при частом вычислении значений, которые обновляются реже, чем смена кадров.

Реализация функций прекрасно описана и прокомментирована в исходниках undersocre